# Sending links to email with nodemailer not working

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm working on an app and I'm using [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to send recovery emails for users to reset their passwords and I'm trying to send a link to a page that will allow them to change their password.  I'm using the following for the body of the email

```
html: '<p>Click <a href="localhost:3000/sessions/recover/' + recovery_token + '">here</a> to reset your password</p>'
```

But when I test it I just get an email with the text and no link, using the ispector shows `<a>here</a>`, so it is sending the a tags, its just not sending the href.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured out the answer after I typed this question, so I guess I'll just answer my own question in case anyone else has the problem. I needed to include the `http://` in the email, when I changed the body of the email to

```
html: '<p>Click <a href="http://localhost:3000/sessions/recover/' + recovery_token + '">here</a> to reset your password</p>'
```

it started working.

Comment: http matters nice explanation

Comment: How can i send deep links?

Comment: What do you mean by deep links?

Comment: Something like this: app-name://domain/reset-password?token=$2a$05$kcFmMVAsYAult7V3KN.J0eO7ynyY1ebAFTFaO82hidJ30ztJpYxYO. Read more here: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/mobile-deep-linking-part-2-using-a-hosted-deep-links-provider-c61fa58d083e

Comment: I&#39;m not sure how to do that, it&#39;s pretty unrealated to this question you should probably find a more relevant question that may have an answer or post a question yourself.